телеграм бот не выводит данные и бесконечно просит ввести один и тот же критерий с кнопки
я пишу код на python для создания telegram бота, который согласно выбранным критериям на кнопках выводит расписание уроков в школе. до момента с вводом дня недели. он просто не видит, что я выбрала и присылает сообщение: "Введите день недели:" бесконечно. я перепробовала все, и код вроде правильно написан. помогите пожалуйста!!
Код прикрепляю ниже
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")
class_chosen = None
letter_chosen = None
day_chosen = None

schedule_5A = "Расписание для 5 класса на понедельник: ..."
schedule_5B = "Расписание для 5 класса на вторник: "
schedule_5B_monday = "Расписание для 5 класса Б на понедельник: "
schedule_5B_tuesday = "Расписание для 5 класса Б на вторник: "

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    itembtn5 = types.KeyboardButton('5')
    itembtn6 = types.KeyboardButton('6')
    itembtn7 = types.KeyboardButton('7')
    itembtn8 = types.KeyboardButton('8')
    itembtn9 = types.KeyboardButton('9')
    itembtn10 = types.KeyboardButton('10')
    itembtn11 = types.KeyboardButton('11')
    markup.add(itembtn5, itembtn6, itembtn7, itembtn8, itembtn9, itembtn10, itembtn11)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберете класс:", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.isdigit())
def handle_class(message):
    global class_chosen
    class_chosen = message.text
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    itembtn_A = types.KeyboardButton('А')
    itembtn_B = types.KeyboardButton('Б')
    itembtn_C = types.KeyboardButton('В')
    itembtn_D = types.KeyboardButton('Г')
    itembtn_E = types.KeyboardButton('Д')
    markup.add(itembtn_A, itembtn_B, itembtn_C, itembtn_D, itembtn_E)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберете букву:", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.isalpha())
def handle_letter(message):
    global letter_chosen
    letter_chosen = message.text
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    itembtn_monday = types.KeyboardButton('Понедельник')
    itembtn_tuesday = types.KeyboardButton('Вторник')
    itembtn_wednesday = types.KeyboardButton('Среда')
    itembtn_thersday = types.KeyboardButton('Четверг')
    itembtn_friday = types.KeyboardButton('Пятница')
    itembtn_saturday = types.KeyboardButton('Суббота')
    markup.add(itembtn_monday, itembtn_tuesday, itembtn_wednesday, itembtn_thersday, itembtn_friday, itembtn_saturday)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберете день недели:", reply_markup=markup)


    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text in ['Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг' , 'Пятница', 'Суббота' ])
    def handle_day(message):
        global day_chosen
        day_chosen = message.text
        if str(class_chosen) == '5' and letter_chosen == 'A':
            if day_chosen == 'Понедельник':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, schedule_5A)
            elif day_chosen == 'Вторник':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, schedule_5B)
        elif str(class_chosen) == '5' and letter_chosen == 'B':
            if day_chosen == 'Понедельник':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, schedule_5B_monday)
            elif day_chosen == 'Вторник':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, schedule_5B_tuesday)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Расписание для выбранного класса и дня недели не найдено.")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_other(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, используйте клавиатуру для выбора опции.")

bot.polling()``` 


https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

bot.register_next_step_handler() вам в помощь.

спасибо большое, все получилось
